# googletranslator "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, translation, google-translate

Using google translation to translate a website content I find the error "No JSON object could be decoded". Here is the code:

```
import requests
from dragnet import extract_content
from googletrans import Translator

url = "https://bitcoin-bitcoin.themedia.jp/posts/4222377/"
r = requests.get(url)
content = extract_content(r.content)
translator = Translator()
text = translator.translate(content, dest='en').text
```

Output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    text = translator.translate(content, dest='en').text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 132, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 63, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: I have a question: why are you translating this, it is already in English.

Comment: @PaulaThomas thanks to repply, I just random picked one of the list, I have the same trouble with all of them. I updated the post, thanks!

Comment: Thabks that confused me! Tried your ammended url - managed to stop the error message by puttinng `json.dumps(content)` but translate returns the same json object! Which is not what is needed.

Comment: Right, I'm testing it there. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, the `content` variable you are passing is not in the expected format. Use `print(type(content))` and `print(content)` to understand what information are you passing and if it is the expected type.

The library you are using is not a Google official library. Find an [official example here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). Is true that you cannot translate a whole website and an equivalent solution is not implemented. You need to read the page and adequate it; or pre-process `content` using dragnet, in your case.

Find below a Python Client Library for Translation API example:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import translate

# Instantiates a client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# The text to translate
text = u'Hello, world!'
# The target language
target = 'ru'

# Translates some text into Russian
translation = translate_client.translate(
    text,
    target_language=target)

print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(translation['translatedText']))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying with google cloud client now and it doesn't have that problem. It seems that the bug is in googletrans, but I don't know what it is. type(content) returns *unicode* (with that strings googletrans works and with that strings that it doesn't).

Comment: Perfect! As I see that you have few reputation points I prompt you to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if they solved your issue/questions. If you still want to receive more answers it's ok leaving them unaccepted for some time.

Comment: I am going to leave it open for some time because I would like to find a solution using the googletrans library, since the google cloud client has another troubles, like requests rate limit. Thanks!